# How to synchronize MS word and Mathtype?

Tags: ms-word, mathtype

I typesetted a document in Microsoft Word 2007 full of math equations typed with mathtype. But when I double click on every equation in the document it will appear another equation in the dialogue mathtype box. I am losing some large amount of my work with this strange happening.

Comment: Is this a programming question? If not, please ask it over at Super User. However, bear in mind it is also not very clear - can you supply a screenshot of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question perfectly. It's caused by Word losing track of the information it needs to know which equation is which. Further, what leads Word to lose this information is copying a MathType equation from one document and pasting it directly into a document -- same document or different one, it doesn't matter. The way to do that type of copy & paste is to copy it from the document, and open MathType at the place in the document where you want to paste it, then paste it into MathType. Don't paste directly into the document.

The equations that have been scrambled in this way must be deleted and replaced with a new equation if you want to edit them. If you don't need to edit them, they will remain in this state forever and will still print nicely.